# Compact spaces with atomless algebra of clopen sets

Tags: general-topology, compactness, boolean-algebra

Let $X$ be a compact (not necessarily metrizable) topological space. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be its algebra of clopen sets and let us assume that $\mathcal{B}$ is atomless, i.e. every non-empty clopen subset of $X$ can be partitioned into two disjoint non-empty clopen subsets.

This happens e.g. when $X$ is totally disconnected. In that case, $X$ is an inverse limit of a system of finite spaces. However, assume that $X$ is not totally disconnected. Can $X$ be expressed as an inverse limit of compacts with finitely many connected (necessarily clopen) components?

Comment: Do you mean to assume all your spaces are Hausdorff? (Or is that included in "compact" for you?)

Comment: In particular, your assertion that $X$ is an inverse limit of a system of finite spaces when $X$ is totally disconnected is wrong without that assumption.

Comment: It's also not true that $\mathcal{B}$ is always atomless when $X$ is a totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space.  (For instance, consider a 1-point compactification of a discrete space.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption that $\mathcal{B}$ is atomless is totally irrelevant here.  Every compact Hausdorff space $X$ is an inverse limit of compact Hausdorff spaces with finitely many components.  To prove this, first note that we may assume $X$ is a subspace of $[0,1]^I$ for some $I$.  Say a subset $\prod_{i\in I}U_i\subseteq[0,1]^I$ is a box if each $U_i$ is an open interval and $U_i=[0,1]$ for all but finitely many $i$.  Every open set in $[0,1]^I$ a union of boxes, so every closed set (in particular, $X$) is an intersection of complements of boxes.  Moreover, it is easy to see that a finite intersection of complements of boxes has finitely many connected components.  So now consider the inverse system consisting of all finite intersections of complements of boxes in $[0,1]^I$ that contain $X$ (and their inclusion maps).  This is an inverse system of compact Hausdorff spaces with finitely many connected component whose limit is $X$.